# Can I switch off redirection from http to https, but still use forse_ssl(config.forse_ssl = true) to generate URLs/assets with https protocol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https

I'm trying to use AWS CloudFront with Rails Application and when I am using config.forse_ssl = true the web site are crushing as CloudFront has redirections and rails app has redirections. 
When I am switching off forse_ssl=false then web site works fine except Ajax requests as all of the ajax requests is not secure anymore. 
Could somebody suggest how to fix that issue? How to switch off redirection to https, but still generate secure urls?

Comment: You can set the origin protocol policy to HTTPS on cloudfront (make sure you have trusted cert on backend), this will make cloudfront to communicate over https and redirection won't occur.

Comment: Yes. That is my configs at the moment, but rails generates all urls with http protocol, so some app functionality is not working anymore. Can I somehow force app to generate all urls with https protocol?

Comment: Can you configure CloudFront to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS so that the only requests reaching your server are HTTPS? This way you can enable `force_ssl`

Comment: Yes. That is what I done. If I use force_ssl=true it creates infinite loop of redirections and website crushes, so I needed to disable forse_ssl=false. Also I have a lot of image_url, asset_url which generates http links instead of https, so I am also wondering can I configure rails to force image_url, etc helpers to generate secure links.